# emberjs input checkValidity and setCustomValidity

Tags: javascript, ember.js, checkvalidity

Is there a way to use checkValidity() setCustomValidity() within ember?  For example, in my controller upon submission I have:

```
var inpObj = this.get('name');
if (inpObj.checkValidity() == false) {
    alert('ok');
}
```

and of course this is my handlebar code:

```
{{input id="name" type="text" value=name placeholder="Your Name" required="true"}}
```

Upon submission of this, I get this error message:

***inpObj.checkValidity is not a function***

Answer (score 0):

You would need to get HTML5 element instead of string to call `checkValidity` function.

```
var inpObj = this.get('name'); // this is only a string
```

You can use jQuery instead:

```
var inpObj = Ember.$('#name')[0];

if (inpObj.checkValidity() == false) {
  alert('ok');
}
```

[Working demo.](https://ember-twiddle.com/c25954548b34390a59b2)

Comment: Solution Works! ... I was hoping to avoid using jQuery if at all possible.  Question, what does Ember.$ do ?  why not just use $

Comment: `Ember.$` is another way to access jQuery if you don't want to access it using global variable `$`. You could avoid jQuery if you would create another component which extends from `Ember.TextField` and integrating validity checks inside it, then propagating information via actions to controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid jQuery, you could set an action on your submit button that runs the valid check for you.

```
<button {{action "submitForm"}}>Your Button</button>
```

Then have an action in your contoller:

```
actions: {
  submitForm() {
    var inpObj = this.get('name');
    if(!inpObj.checkValidity()) {
      // error handling
      alert('ok');
    } else {
      // save your data, or whatever you need to do
      this.transitionTo('some.route');
    }
  }
}
```